# Phantomjs change object property inside page evaluate

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm new to JavaScript and PhantomJS. I'm trying to store links from a webpage and then modify. The problem is that I can't modify my array after `page.evaluate`.

```
var player = 0;
var links = page.evaluate(function() {
    var a = document.querySelectorAll(".link[rel='nofollow']:not(#bg)");
    for(var i =0; i < a.length; i++) {
        array.push({
            "html":a[i].innerHTML,
            "link":a[i].href
        }
        );
    }
   return array;
});

//Not setting 1 as a value
links[player]["link"] = 1;
```

I think that It's happening because I have already set player value when the function is executed, but is there way that I could modify this value?

Comment: `player[player]`? You probably meant to use `links[player]`

Comment: Just edited now, I wrote wrong yesterday

Comment: Is there anyone who knows how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code replaces a copy of a copy of a reference to the actual data that you want to change. Of course, that cannot work.

If you want to change a property/content on a page, then you need to access the page and change it:

```
var player = 0;
page.evaluate(function(player) {
    var a = document.querySelectorAll(".link[rel='nofollow']:not(#bg)");
    a[player].href = "1";
}, player);
```

I don't think that "1" is an appropriate value for the href value, but it looks like that is what you want to do.